# linebreak in \printdate?

Tags: isodate

How can I achieve that the printed dates obeys line breaks?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[english]{isodate}

\begin{document}

a a a a a aa a a a a aa a a a a aa a a a a aa a a a a a aa a a a a a aa a a a a a aa a a a a a aa a a a a aa a a a a aa a a a a a\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa \printdate{2017-05-12}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/isodate/isodate.pdf) of the `isodate` package (page 5):

> By default, the original and short original format prints unbreakable
> spaces between the parts of the dates, e.g., `19~May~2001`. If you
> want to allow breakable spaces or other characters, you can redefine
> the spaces using `\isospacebeforeday`, `\isospacebeforemonth`, and
> `\isospacebeforeyear`:
>
> `\isospacebeforeyear{\ }`
>
> leads to `19~May\ 2001`. Notice that the space is written as `\`  to
> ensure that the space is not getting lost under all circumstances.

MWE for the space before the year:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[english]{isodate}
\isospacebeforeyear{\ }
\begin{document}

a a a a a aa a a a a aa a a a a aa a a a a aa a a a a a aa a a a a a aa a a a a a aa a a a a a aa a a a a aa a a a a aa a a a a a\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa \printdate{2017-05-12}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]